# Update display label when changed numericupdown value and button click

Tags: c#, for-loop, nested, nested-loops, numericupdown

I have this nested for loop project where i have to display a triangle with the asterisks by getting the value from NumericUpDown control and DisplayButton click. Well, it does the work, it displays the correct shape and number of stars.

But when I try to change the value from the NumericUpDown control, the display label does not update, instead, it would just add up underneath the previous result. I need the display label to update/change when the value is changed from the numericupdown, and when the DisplayButton is clicked.

```
private void displayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {

                int counter = (int)sideLengthNumericUpDown.Value;
                for (int r = 0; r < counter; r++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c <= r; c++)
                    {
                        displayLabel.Text += counter.ToString("*");

                    }
                    displayLabel.Text += counter.ToString("\n");
                }
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {

                int counter = (int)sideLengthNumericUpDown.Value;
                for (int r = counter; r > 0; r--)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < r; c++)
                    {
                        displayLabel.Text += counter.ToString("*");

                    }
                    displayLabel.Text += counter.ToString("\n");
                }
            }
```

Comment: You just need to reset label text at the beginning of this method `displayLabel.ResetText();` and close this question

Comment: Ohh I see.. thank you!!